# How to pass image data from ImagePicker(UIViewController) to UIView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage

So im trying to pass my image data from the ImagePicker that i selected to my UIbutton on my UIView. I have search it but i am not familiar on how to use delegates and core data. If there is an much more easy and simple way to do that can you help me. BTW i am using ImagePicker Library. I just want to pass my `AddItemPhotos` images to my `btn_firstPhoto` and `btn_secondPhoto`. Thank you in advance

```
class AddItemImage: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var btn_firstPhoto: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn_secondPhoto: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
//    btn_firstPhoto.setImage(AddItemPhotos[0], for: UIControlState)
//    btn_secondPhoto.setImage(AddItemPhotos[1], for: UIControlState)
    }
}


class AddItemView: UIViewController, ImagePickerDelegate {

    var AddItemPhotos: [UIImage] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupPicker()
    }

    func setupPicker() {
        var config = Configuration()
        config.doneButtonTitle = "Finish"
        config.noImagesTitle = "Sorry! There are no images here!"
        config.recordLocation = false
        config.allowMultiplePhotoSelection = true

        let imagePicker = ImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.imageLimit = 2
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - ImagePickerDelegate
    func cancelButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func wrapperDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {

    }

    func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
        AddItemPhotos = images
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: So how are you triggering this image picker? it is in a separate view controller with your UIView or something else?

Comment: Yes, It is a seperate view for the UIView. When my UIViewController(AddItemView) loads it triggers the image picker.

Comment: Ok. What is the relationship between AddItemImage and AddItemView then? Your picker view is presented over AddItemView. Is AddItemImage a view on your AddItemView view controller?

Comment: AddItemView is a UIViewController and AddItemImage is a xib UIView

Comment: And AddItemImage is created inside your AddItemView as a subview?

Comment: Kinda. I am using a library called Eureka and this is my code which shows my`AddItemImage`.             

`Section(header: "", footer: "You can select up to 2 photos for your item.") { section in
                
                var header = HeaderFooterView<AddItemImage>(.nibFile(name: "AddItemPhoto", bundle: nil))
                    header.height = {150}
                    header.onSetupView = { view, _ in
                    }
                section.header = header
            }`